# How to add field in 2 tables same time?

Tags: python, orm, odoo, openerp-8

I have model table called student,the student should be registered in 1 group and 1 standard.

I want that when choosing  standard and group on creating student 
the student should automatically added to standard table model and group table model

here is my fields in student model table

```
'standard_id': fields.many2one('fci.standard', string='Standard', required=True),
'group_id': fields.many2one('fci.standard.groups',string='Groups(s)'),
```

and here is my field that should be updated in standard model table

```
'student_ids': fields.many2many('fci.student', 'student_standard_rel', 'fci_student_standard_id', 'standard_id',
                                        string='Student(s)'),
'groups_ids': fields.many2many('fci.standard.groups', 'standard_group_rel', 'fci_standard_group_id', 'standard_group_id',
                                        string='Groups(s)'),
```

and here is my fields in group table model:

```
'student_ids': fields.many2many('fci.student', 'students_groups_rel', 'group_student_rel', 'student_group_id',string='Student(s)'),
```

I have idea maybe a solution to (to create related field but i can't do it with many2many fields )

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, why you are using **many2many** when it's **many2one** in the other side.

For consistency of your architecture, you need only to use **one2many** relation in each standard and group model tables.

If you did it likely, the student will be automatically added to corresponding tables.